# OSRM functions vs. GoogleMaps functions

Tags: java, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

Is there a URL in OSRM (http://project-osrm.org/) that I could call in a JAVA program and parse the Json file returned, as for instance:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=rue+de+la+chambre+33+paris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have it ! Nominatim (from the Latin, 'by name') is a tool to search OSM data by name and address and to generate synthetic addresses of OSM points (reverse geocoding)

http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json&q=42+rue+de+la+Folie-M%C3%A9ricourt+11e+Paris